# I cannot open Safari, when I did open -a Safari error -10810 appeared

Tags: mac, safari

[image]

I tried searching what error -10810 is but nothing came up on Google. Any idea on how to fix this or go around this?

Comment: Does Safari open okay if just opening it from Finder? Have you tried running First Aid on the e.g. Macintosh HD in Disk Utility?

Comment: I'd also try reseting the **Launch Services Database** from **Terminal** with the following _command_: `/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Support/lsregister -kill -r -domain local -domain system -domain user`

Comment: Possibly related: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/181026/lsopenurlswithrole-failed-with-error-10810-cant-open-install-os-x-yosemite

Comment: If you Google "error -10810", with quote marks, you get results, fyi.

Comment: IIRC, I have also seen this error code when the users in the terminal and graphical sessions differed. I too failed to find anything in my online search.

Answer (score 5):

When opening an *application* with the `open` *command*, you should use the `-a` *option*, e.g:

```
open -a "Safari"
```

From the [man page](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/open.1.html) for the `open` *command*:

> **-a application**
>        Specifies the application to use for opening the file

**Note:** If you use the `-a` *option*, you typically do not need to specify the *pathname* or even use the *.app extension.* Just the format as in the example shown above should work.

---

In **Terminal**, the *executable* permission (and others) output of:

```
ls -l /Applications/Safari.app/Contents/MacOS/Safari
```

Should be:

```
-rwxr-xr-x
```

If not, then in **Terminal**, run the following *command*:

```
sudo chmod 0755 /Applications/Safari.app/Contents/MacOS/Safari
```

This will ensure the proper *permissions* on the **Safari** *executable* and should stop you from getting the error you've got.

Comment: same error occurs

Comment: If there's a permissions problem, "Fix Permissions" in Disk Utility should deal with it.

Comment: @Barmar, Fix Permissions has been removed from Disk Utility for some time now, so it depends on what version of the OS the OP is running. That said, there is nothing wrong with manually checking it in order to eliminate it as the cause of the issue and if so manually applying the proper permissions.

Comment: lol I bet they removed it because users were using it any time they had a problem, but permissions were rarely the cause. Now this user needs it and it's not there. :)