# TeamViewer "FAILED TO establish the default connection to the WindowServer"

Tags: macos, mojave, ssh, remote-desktop

I need TeamViewer on my Mac to work remotely. I installed it via ssh using the command line

```
brew cask install teamviewer
```

which worked fine.

However, I seem to be unable to configure TeamViwer from the command line. Due to Corona, I cannot personally access the Mac at the moment, which means I have to do everything via ssh.

I tried

```
$ /Applications/TeamViewer.app/Contents/MacOS/TeamViewer
```

which fails with

> _RegisterApplication(), FAILED TO establish the default connection to the WindowServer, _CGSDefaultConnection() is NULL. 
>   Could not find domain for 
>   Could not find domain for 
>   2020-03-23 18:53:18.935 TeamViewer[1695:9920] +[NSXPCSharedListener endpointForReply:withListenerName:]: an error occurred while attempting to obtain endpoint for listener 'ClientCallsAuxiliary': Connection interrupted

and then stops until I exit with Ctrl+C.

I also tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24324797/1574054), which gave me

```
$ open /Applications/TeamViewer.app
```

> LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed with error -610 for the file /Applications/TeamViewer.app.

and

```
$ sudo open /Applications/TeamViewer.app
```

> LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed with error -10810 for the file /Applications/TeamViewer.app.

Furthermore, the path `Library/Preferences/com.teamviewer.*` does not exist.

What do I have to do next? What else can I try?

Comment: See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/181026/lsopenurlswithrole-failed-with-error-10810-cant-open-install-os-x-yosemite [I don't want to vote to close as a duplicate, as I have one-vote-close rights for this tag, so let us know if that helps]

Comment: @Tetsujin Unfortunately, none of the answers work... I suspect it has something to do with the answer of TinyTimZamboni. However, I can obviously not access my Mac right now

Comment: I think the Mac cannot open a window/the window server because no on is physically logged in; only me via ssh.

Answer (score 2):

This should work (sudo privs required!)

- Login with ssh on the remote Mac
- Enter:

  ```
  sudo /System/Library/CoreServices/RemoteManagement/ARDAgent.app/Contents/Resources/kickstart  -activate -configure -access -on -privs -all -restart -agent
  ```

  to enable remote management
- open Screen Sharing locally (/System/Library/CoreServices/Applications/Screen Sharing.app)
- Enter the IP of the remote Mac
- Enter your remote user creds
- Log in with your remote user creds at the login screen
- Launch and configure TeamViewer

Depending on the security settings of the remote network (firewall etc.) you have to use the same tunnel/channel as the ssh connection.

The steps above only work for macOS up to High Sierra (10.13.6).

---

In macOS Mojave and later `kickstart` only works with managed devices and special profiles, if screen sharing wasn't enabled previously:

[Use the kickstart command-line utility in macOS Mojave 10.14 and later](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT209161)

Eventually, you have to access the remote Mac personally and set up screen sharing in System Prefs > Sharing (to access it via VNC) or launch and configure TeamViewer.

Comment: When I try to access the Mac via screen sharing, nothing happens. It seems the mac cannot be reached... Previously, I also tried other methods of Remote Management including access via VNC from Windows 10 and Ubuntu. Neither worked.

Comment: I checked that when I was still able to access it physically; firewall (at least mac-default one) is disabled. Maybe some firewall somewhere along the network blocks this...

Comment: I use a VPN to get into the network. Then I ssh into the Mac via its local IP.

Comment: Side note: If possible I want to be able to connect to the Mac from a Windws 10 machine and VNC (without relying on using my Macbook and RemoteManagement...). This hasn't worked so far...